# My current course has me using MySQL workbench and my tables are only one off. I can not find the flaw in my coding and ZYbooks does not like me. :)

Tags: mysql

Write and run seven SQL statements:

Explain the query SELECT * FROM film WHERE title = 'ALONE TRIP';.

In the EXPLAIN result, column key is null, indicating no index is available for the query. Column rows is 100, indicating all rows are read. The query executes a table scan and is slow.

Create an index idx_title on the title column.

Explain the query of step 1 again.

In the EXPLAIN result, column key has value idx_title, indicating the query uses the index on title. Column rows is 1, indicating only one table row is read. The query is fast.

Explain the query SELECT * FROM film WHERE title > 'ALONE TRIP';.

In the EXPLAIN result, column key is null, indicating the query does not use the idx_title index. Column rows is 100, indicating all rows are read. Since the query has > in the WHERE clause rather than =, the query executes a table scan and is slow.

Explain the query SELECT rating, count(*) FROM film GROUP BY rating;

In the EXPLAIN result, column key is null, indicating no index is available for the query. Column rows is 100, indicating all rows are read. The query executes a table scan and is slow.

Create an index idx_rating on the rating column.

Explain the query of step 5 again.

In the EXPLAIN result, column key has value idx_rating, indicating the query reads rating values from the index. The query uses an index scan, which is faster than a table scan (step 5).

I wrote:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM film WHERE title = 'ALONE TRIP';
CREATE INDEX idx_title ON film(title);
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM film WHERE title = 'ALONE TRIP';
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM film WHERE title = 'ALONE TRIP';
EXPLAIN SELECT rating, Count(*) FROM film GROUP BY rating;
CREATE INDEX idx_rating ON film(rating);
EXPLAIN SELECT rating, Count(*) FROM film GROUP BY rating;
```

but the columns are not matching for some reason and I can not find my error. Also, I am using "Sakila" as a reference.

Comment: please *show* what you mean by "only one off", "columns not matching".  What are you doing and what is it showing and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: what is ZYbooks and what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: the current sakila data seems to already have the idx_title index, is that what is confusing you?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT last_name, first_name, ROUND(AVG(length), 0) AS average
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE title = "ALONE TRIP"
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
ORDER BY average;

EXPLAIN
SELECT last_name, first_name, ROUND(AVG(length), 0) AS average
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE title < "ALONE TRIP"
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
ORDER BY average;

EXPLAIN
SELECT last_name, first_name, ROUND(AVG(length), 0) AS average
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE title > "ALONE TRIP"
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
ORDER BY average;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

just change line 4 to >, you wrote =

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of the page. But it should. Can you [edit] to make more obvious that you mean this to be according to [answer]?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35703661)